# How to use the Wronskian to find the in homogeneous solution of an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

Suppose I have an ODE in the form:

$ y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = f(x) $

Suppose now that I have obtained the solution to the equation

$ y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0 $

which is in the form

$ y(x) = c_1 y_1(x) + c_2 y_2(x) $

My textbook suggests that it is possible to use the Wronskian of the solution in order to obtain a solution to the inhomogeneous equation, hence getting the general solution to the equation.

For example, the homogeneous solution to:

$y'' + 6y' + 2y = 1 $

is $ c_1exp(-3+\sqrt 7)x + c_2exp(-3-\sqrt 7)x $

How is then one able to use the Wronskian to obtain the general solution (which I am able to derive ($y_p = 0.5$) by other methods, but not this one).

Comment: use the formula that gives the particular solution in function of the wronskian

Comment: What would that formula be?

Comment: Saheb has posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **method of variation of parameters** in such cases. The general solution is $$y(x)=p(x)y_1(x)+q(x)y_2(x),$$ where $p(x)=-\int \dfrac{y_2(x)f(x)}{w(y_1,y_2)} dx+c_1$ and $q(x)=\int \dfrac{y_1(x)f(x)}{w(y_1,y_2)} dx+c_2$ and $w(y_1,y_2)$ be the Wronskian of $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$.

Comment: I am familiar with the variation of parameters, I usually solve the simultaneous equations:
$\begin{cases} g_1'u_1 + g_2'u_2 = 0\\ g_1'u_1' + g_2'u_2' = f(x) \end{cases}$

where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are the solutions of the homogeneous equation.


$\\$ Is that the equivalent of what you suggested? I am asking because my textbook says "_Use the Wronskian method to show that the ordinary differential equation_"

Comment: Yes. This is equivalent. Solve for $g_1'$ and $g_2'$ and see what happens.

Comment: Ok what does $f(x)$ refers to?

Comment: $f(x)$ refers to the nono-homogeneous part of your ODE .